# What does exposing my service account credentials expose specifically in Firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm making a simple java based game and I want to use `Google Firebase` to store simple variables for the game in real-time.

The only option that `Google Cloud` supports in `Java` is to use the [Firebase Admin SDK.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)  The one problem with this is that it will leave my service credentials exposed in the client.

I'm honestly fine if somebody gets the credentials and messes up my project, what matters the most is if somebody can get access to my account.

I'm only going to be sending the final project to my teacher and friends. Or maybe I'm just doing this the completely wrong way, if anybody has a better solution that would be great!

Comment: the admin sdk is meant to be used server side... DO NOT SHIP A CLIENT APP WITH YOUR CREDENTIALS

Answer (score 1):

Turning over your default service account to anyone grants them the ability to modify pretty much anything within your project, as the permissions granted to it will allow.  Since this can vary, you should read the documentation about services accounts:

- [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)
- [Understanding service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts)

It is generally a bad idea to turn over a service account to anyone that you don't explicitly trust with your billing.